# GitLab: Can’t register runner (with correct token!) - clean/latest docker install

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

**Note: It seems everyone else with this problem is using the wrong token - I'm using the one from the Admin Area -> Overview -> Runners under "Set up a shared Runner manually", so I'm sure it's correct.**

I'm trying to get a basic setup of GitLab with one shared runner working from docker containers, but I keep getting this when I try to register:

```
ERROR: Registering runner... forbidden (check registration token)  runner=Ds-3E59o
PANIC: Failed to register this runner. Perhaps you are having network problems
```

These are the steps I take (tested from fresh by removing `/srv/gitlab`):

1. Run GitLab:

```
# As per https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/docker/#pre-configure-docker-container.
sudo docker run --detach \
  --hostname gitlab.example.com \
  --env GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG="external_url 'http://gitlab.example.com/'; gitlab_rails['lfs_enabled'] = true;" \
  --publish 443:443 --publish 80:80 --publish 22:22 \
  --name gitlab \
  --restart always \
  --volume /srv/gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab \
  --volume /srv/gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab \
  --volume /srv/gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab \
  gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest
```

2. Run the runner:

```
# As per: https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/docker.html#docker-image-installation.
docker run -d --name gitlab-runner --restart always \
  -v /srv/gitlab-runner/config:/etc/gitlab-runner \
  -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
  gitlab/gitlab-runner:latest
```

3. Wait for gitlab to start, set root password, login as root, go to Configure GitLab -> Overview -> Runners, copy the access token.
4. Attempt to register the runner:

```
# As per: https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/register/index.html#one-line-registration-command.
docker run --rm -v /srv/gitlab-runner/config:/etc/gitlab-runner gitlab/gitlab-runner register \
    --non-interactive \
    --executor "docker" \
    --docker-image alpine:latest \
    --url "http://gitlab.example.com/" \
    --registration-token "VMTMR8TysySosb6xuTLZ" \
    --description "docker-runner" \
    --tag-list "docker" \
    --run-untagged="true" \
    --locked="false" \
    --access-level="not_protected"
```

At this point, I get the error shown above.

I know it seem weird to run the runner and register it while it's running but 1. the documentation has it this way and 2. I get the same result when registering first.

Am I doing something stupid?

(Note: Copied from forum.gitlab.com, but I wasn't having much luck there: https://forum.gitlab.com/t/cant-register-runner-clean-latest-docker-install/30884)

Comment: You sure you have the _right_ token? When I was installing runner for us, I grabbed one from `https://gitlab.com/<project>/<repo>/-/settings/ci_cd` and there is a token under `Set up a specific Runner manually`

Comment: Ah, I should have stressed this - yes. Annoyingly, everyone else has this problem.

I've tried the token from Admin Area -> Overview -> Runners and from an individual project (don't have one set up in a new/clean invocation of everything but have tried) and neither works.

Answer (score 0):

I tried using host networking (i.e. adding `--network host`) to the `gitlab` container, and it worked. No idea why but I'd appreciate any insight anyone has.